Remove load bearing wall in Garage
I have a 2 car garage that was either split at one point or it was always like that. There is an apartment above and I want to remove most of the wall between the 2. Is there a calculation I can do to determine how much of the wall I can take out and how big the beam needs to be. Concrete floor, 2x4 wall. About 16’ long.

Start with the max load on it. But consult with a structural engineer - this is not something to duck up...

The beam size is only one part.  Support posts and their placing, plus the posts footing size are other parts to consider.

First you should determine whether the wall is actually load-bearing.  Does the wall continue above, into the apartment?  Does the wall parallel the garage ceiling joists, or cross them?

A wall made of 2 x 4s is likely not load-bearing. Are there columns inside it? Those might be load-bearing. IF you have any doubt, do not be a cheapskate, pay a pro, the last thing you need is to cause a collapse, the cost of a pro vs the cost of that disaster is not even close.

@CaptainChaos, that's flat wrong. Most basement and other interior bearing walls, not to mention most garage walls, are 2x4 in my region. They're almost never upsized solely because they're carrying a floor or roof. The capacity of a 2x4 stud is more than adequate.

There's not enough information here to answer. The details of the load being carried, as well as the footing situation are critical.

We need much more information. Look in ceiling, if the trusses are 12 inches and larger and go from one side of exterior wall to other side of exterior wall, the wall is not load bearing. It was just put there to divide room. Wall can come down without an issue.
If any trusses are less than 12 and landed on top and using the wall as a place to bear the load, Time to call someone that does that work.
